# What is the geometric dimensions of turbo pumps present in SSME?

Tags: spacecraft-development, ssme, turbopump, development, dimensions

[Here](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2011/ph240/nguyen1/docs/SSME_PRESENTATION.pdf) is a really well documented and detailed explanation of the SSME engine.

Looking through this, one can notice that there are no details of the dimensions.

I would like to know about the geometric dimension of the turbo pumps present in SSME, like

- inlet and outlet pipe diameter,
- height of the impeller housing,
- blade angle

I have been working out the numbers of the turbo pumps, but the reference material does not provide these mentioned parameters.

Comment: Back in the 90s when I was writing a simulation of the SSME for NASA JSC, I couldn't get this information. We ended up measuring the best pictures we could get and estimating. We used the blade angle coefficent as the data-matching parameter.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Does that linked Rockerdyne document has any reference images? Or can you refer to any good images, for many of what I get on internet is the assembled picture of the engine

Comment: If you're just trying to do a simple simulation, I wouldn't worry about this information. Use the performance data that you *can* get, and estimate the remaining parameters, lumping them together if you can. For example, you can calculate the LPOT power (it's a hydraulic turbine) from the shaft speed, flowrate, and a data matching parameter that has all that geometry baked into it. You can calculate its pump power from the flow and shaft speed as well, lumping all the unknown parameters together. Curve-fit the data matching parameters to the shaft speed if you have to.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yeah, trying it out. I will revert back if I have any doubts. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From:
https://gandalf.azureedge.net/shuttle.html

Specifically page 4-19:
https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/SSME_MPS_Info/RSS-8559-1-1-7%20-%20Inspection%20Criteria%20for%20Space%20Shuttle%20Main%20Engine%20and%20Chromalux%20Engine%20Drying%20manual.pdf

You see the OD's of the lines, throughout this document are the measurements of many other lines:
[image]